# Reliable name resolution in local networks

Tags: router, dns, android, lan, openwrt

I find that name resolution of local machines in home networks is getting less and less reliable, especially on mobile devices. In an attempt to secure DNS queries, some browsers/devices always use a public DNS server, DNS over HTTPS (DoH), etc. The local DNS server is no longer contacted.

What can be done to get reliable local name resolution - assuming you have an "open", configurable router? Changes on the clients are not feasible, as there are too many different problems in Android/iOS versions and the browsers.

Comment: In a home network, DNS is provided by the ISP - not your own network. If you are unhappy with the DNS provided by your ISP, almost any router provides an alternate DNS

Comment: @John: Nearly all home routers do include an internal DNS caching resolver which handles queries before forwarding them to the ISP. (Some routers just outright run dnsmasq for the task.) In addition to providing the caching service, frequently the router's internal DNS server is also authoritative for a made-up domain like `.home` or `.lan` with data obtained from the DHCP lease table.

Comment: Main DNS by ISP remains best in my view

Comment: To clarify: This question is about resolving host names of hosts within the LAN more reliably. It is not about how to find a better public DNS server, like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the DNS resolver for most operating systems. For example, to use [Cloudflare's DNS lookup, 1.1.1.1,](http:///https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setting-up-1.1.1.1/) in Android 9,

- In *Settings | Network & internet | Advanced | Private DNS*, Select *Private DNS provider hostname*.
- Enter *one.one.one.one* or *1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com* and click *Save*.
- Verify you're using Cloudflare DNS by going to *1.1.1.1/help* and verify DNS over TLS is enabled.

**Caveat:** In some locations or for specific ISP's, you must use the *default* DNS lookup; Cloudflare is blocked.